# Having trouble with serial ports communicating?

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

Serial port communication isn't working in Linux on my machine.
How to solve?

I have a USB to NULL-modem to USB plugged in.  Using this Serial cable in Windows works fine.  Can transfer 100MB file in Windows.
In Ubuntu Linux.  I am having trouble.  I can't even get command line to work.

---

Setting up ports:

```
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/ttyS0
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/ttyS4

crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Feb 10 14:31 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 4, 68 Feb 10 14:20 /dev/ttyS4

dmesg | grep ttyS
[    0.412092] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.433676] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0xf0e0 (irq = 19, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

---

Communication:

```
On one terminal:
cat -v < /dev/ttyS0   or   cat -v < /dev/ttyS4


On another terminal:
echo -e "\x7E\x03\xD0\xAF und normaler Text" > /dev/ttyS0
```

---

```
stty -aF /dev/ttyS0
speed 57600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = <undef>; quit = <undef>; erase = <undef>; kill = <undef>; eof = <undef>;
eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = <undef>; stop = <undef>;
susp = <undef>; rprnt = <undef>; werase = <undef>; lnext = <undef>;
discard = <undef>; min = 0; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
-echoctl -echoke -flusho -extproc
```

---

```
stty -aF /dev/ttyS4
speed 57600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = <undef>; quit = <undef>; erase = <undef>; kill = <undef>; eof = <undef>;
eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = <undef>; stop = <undef>;
susp = <undef>; rprnt = <undef>; werase = <undef>; lnext = <undef>;
discard = <undef>; min = 0; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
-echoctl -echoke -flusho -extproc
```

---

This is the documentation:

https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90001541/tasks/t_use_terminals.htm?TocPath=Get%20started%20with%20MicroPython%7C_____8

Comment: What does `stty -aF /dev/ttyS0` command say (and similarly for /dev/ttyS4)?

Comment: updated with results

Comment: NOTE:  Picocom shows port to port communication works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it's a USB-to-serial device? Then the device name will most likely be of the form `/dev/ttyUSB*`, not `/dev/ttyS*`. If you have just one such device, the name will probably be `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

The very first Linux step in the instructions you linked also says:

> Open a terminal in Linux and type `picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Your `/dev/ttyS0` looks like a normal physical serial port (on a laptop, it might be available using a docking station only), and since `/dev/ttyS4` seems to be related to PCI ID 0000:00:16.3 in your `dmesg` output, it's probably the Intel AMT/MEI serial-over-LAN management endpoint. Neither of those has anything at all to do with USB-to-serial devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need somebody to do flow control. If the serial line is emulated, you need to behave as it were really a serial line.

One possibility is to establish network. You can do it using good old slip:

1. `slattach /dev/ttyS0` on one side, `slattach /dev/ttyS4` on the other. Now you have a new "network adapter" called probably `sl0` on either side.
2. You can give it an address (e. g. using `ip addr aadd 172.16.16.1/30 brd + dev sl0`) and make it active (`ip link set sl0 up`). Similarly on the other side (but with the other address).
3. Then use it as any other network connection.

Other possibilities include file transfer utilities like kermit.
I am afraid, simple `cat` or `echo` wouldn't be enough.